# Why does the asyncio's event loop suppress the KeyboardInterrupt on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.4, python-asyncio, keyboardinterrupt

I have this really small test program which does nothing apart from a executing an `asyncio` event loop:

```
import asyncio
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

When I run this program on Linux and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the program will terminate correctly with a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. On Windows pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does nothing (tested with Python 3.4.2). A simple inifinite loop with `time.sleep()` raises the `KeyboardInterrupt` correctly even on Windows:

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(3600)
```

Why does the asyncio's event loop suppress the KeyboardInterrupt on Windows?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a bug, sure.

See [issue on python bug-tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue23057) for the problem solving progress.

Comment: Ctrl-C on WIndows is going to work in Python 3.8  https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.8.html#asyncio

Answer (score 23):

There is workaround for Windows. Run another corouting which wake up loop every second and allow loop to react on keyboard interrupt

Example with Echo server from asyncio doc

```
async def wakeup():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_server(EchoServerClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# add wakeup HACK
loop.create_task(wakeup())

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to exit the program and don't need to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt`, the [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module provides a simpler (and more efficient) workaround:

```py
# This restores the default Ctrl+C signal handler, which just kills the process
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

# Now the event loop is interruptable
import asyncio
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Does this solution clean up the socket connections?

Comment: @Jiu This just causes the process to exit.  Any open sockets will be closed by the operating system.  See https://superuser.com/questions/375604 for more info.