# python aiohttp into existing event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm testing aiohttp and asyncio. I want the same event loop to have a socket, http server, http client.

I'm using this sample code:

```
@routes.get('/')
async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(text="Hello, world")

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes(routes)
web.run_app(app)
```

The problem is `run_app` is blocking. I want to add the http server into an existing event loop, that I create using:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> The problem is `run_app` is blocking. I want to add the http server into an existing event loop

`run_app` is just a convenience API. To hook into an existing event loop, you can directly instantiate the `AppRunner`:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# add stuff to the loop
...

# set up aiohttp - like run_app, but non-blocking
runner = aiohttp.web.AppRunner(app)
loop.run_until_complete(runner.setup())
site = aiohttp.web.TCPSite(runner)    
loop.run_until_complete(site.start())

# add more stuff to the loop
...

loop.run_forever()
```

In asyncio 3.8 and later you can use `asyncio.run()`:

```
async def main():
    # add stuff to the loop, e.g. using asyncio.create_task()
    ...

    runner = aiohttp.web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = aiohttp.web.TCPSite(runner)    
    await site.start()

    # add more stuff to the loop, if needed
    ...

    # wait forever
    await asyncio.Event().wait()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks, any reason why the server wont terminate on SIGINT (pressing CTRL+C)? I'm using windows powershell

Comment: @user3599803 Not using Windows, sorry, but googling possibly reveals it as [a long-standing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27480967/1600898) in asyncio.

Comment: @user3599803 https://stackoverflow.com/a/37420223/2955584 check this answer for terminating the script in windows machine

Comment: Just a note how to specify IP and port, which takes some googling: `site = web.TCPSite(runner, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)`

Answer (score 12):

For the future traveler from Google, here is a simpler way.

```
async def main():
    await aio.gather(
        web._run_app(app, port=args.port),
        SomeotherTask(),
        AndAnotherTask()
    )

aio.run(main())
```

Explanation:
`web.runapp` is a thin wrapper over internal function `web._runapp`. The function uses the old style way of getting the eventloop and then calling `loop.run_until_complete`.

We replace it with `aio.gather` alongside other tasks that we want to run concurrently and use the `aio.run` to schedule them

[Source](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/web.py#L419)

Comment: They now provide the Application Runner API to allow for this use case:  https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#application-runners

Comment: Please avoid using private APIs in StackOverflow answers. Methods starting with `_`, such as `_run_app`, can be removed, renamed, or change meaning without prior notice.

Comment: I had trouble using this **private** member function but was able to use the [app runner example](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#application-runners).