# Can't stop aiohttp websocket server

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I can't cancel my aiohttp websocket server from within the application. I want to stop the server and shutdown when I get a "cancel" string
from the client. Yes, I get it, and I finish my co-routine (websocket_handler), but there are three co-routines from the aiohttp library which still continue working.

[image]

Of course, I can invoke `asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()` at the end of my co-routine, but is there a graceful way for stopping aiohttp server?

From my code one can see that I've tried to use   `Application().on_shutdown.append()`, but it failed.

What is the right way?

#!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import os
    import asyncio
    import signal
    import weakref

```
import aiohttp.web
from   aiohttp import ClientConnectionError, WSCloseCode

# This restores the default Ctrl+C signal handler, which just kills the process
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480967/why-does-the-asyncios-event-loop-suppress-the-keyboardinterrupt-on-windows
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

HOST = os.getenv('HOST', 'localhost')
PORT = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8881))

async def testhandle(request):
    #Сопрограмма одрабатывающая http-запрос по адресу "http://127.0.0.1:8881/test"
    print("server: into testhandle()")
    return aiohttp.web.Response(text='Test handle')

async def websocket_handler(request):
    #Сопрограмма одрабатывающая ws-запрос по адресу "http://127.0.0.1:8881"   
    print('Websocket connection starting')
    ws = aiohttp.web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)
    request.app['websockets'].add(ws)
    print('Websocket connection ready')
    try:
        async for msg in ws:
            if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
                if msg.data == 'close':
                    print(msg.data) 
                    break    
                else:
                    print(msg.data)
                    await ws.send_str("You said: {}".format(msg.data))
            elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
                print('ws connection closed with exception %s' %
                    ws.exception())             
    except (asyncio.CancelledError, ClientConnectionError):   
        pass    # Тут оказываемся когда, клиент отвалился. 
                # В будущем можно тут освобождать ресурсы. 
    finally:
        print('Websocket connection closed')
        request.app['websockets'].discard(ws)
        #pending = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
        #asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
    return ws

async def on_shutdown(app):
    for ws in set(app['websockets']):
        await ws.close(code=WSCloseCode.GOING_AWAY, message='Server shutdown')   

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app  = aiohttp.web.Application()
    app['websockets'] = weakref.WeakSet()
    app.on_shutdown.append(on_shutdown)  
    app.add_routes([aiohttp.web.get('/', websocket_handler)])        #, aiohttp.web.get('/test', testhandle)   

    try:
        aiohttp.web.run_app(app, host=HOST, port=PORT, handle_signals=True)
        print("after run_app")
    except Exception as exc:
        print ("in exception")
    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the correct answer is simply:

```py
raise aiohttp.web.GracefulExit()
```

After catching the exception, it calls all the handlers appended to the `on_shutdown` and `on_cleanup` signals and dies.

[One can see in the source code](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/1b4b89cccbdd2d9418b6ab4dcf7a2d7472b60227/aiohttp/web.py#L516) the `aiohttp.web.run_app()` waits for two exceptions: `GracefulExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt`. While the latter is rather uninteresting, following the trace of `GracefulExit` can lead you to [this place in `web_runner.py`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/1b4b89cccbdd2d9418b6ab4dcf7a2d7472b60227/aiohttp/web_runner.py#L279-L280), that registers `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` signal handlers to a function with `raise GracefulExit()`.

Indeed, I also managed to gracefully shut it down by raising the `signal.SIGINT` or `signal.SIGTERM` from itself, e.g.

```py
import signal
signal.raise_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

This was tested to work on Fedora Linux 34, Python 3.9.7, aiohttp 3.7.4.

Comment: The second option (signal.raise_signal(signal.SIGINT)) is much better because it doesn't print exception messages to the console. Great answer!

Comment: how can another thread raise the appropriate signal?   need to add an endpoint for shutting down, seems unsafe

Comment: @ErikAronesty Signaling from another thread is likely [OK as long as you expect to handle the signal in the main thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads) (and make sure all things get properly cleaned up after that). You didn't provide much info, but it seems like you could do that in an `on_shutdown` handler (that gets executed in the aiohttp's running_loop thread). Naturally, all threading business is up to you to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v3.0.1/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.Application.shutdown

```
app.shutdown()
app.cleanup()
```

After shutdown you should also do cleanup()

Comment: The link is no longer correct and app.shutdown() and app.cleanup() don't actually seem to do anything apart from calling the related callbacks.